# How to register all interface on assembly in Scrutor similar StructureMap

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, inversion-of-control, scrutor

How to register all interface in assembly with `scan` extension without write all separated in ASP.NET Core 2?

in StructureMap:

```cs
Scan(_ =>
{
    // Declare which assemblies to scan
    _.Assembly("StructureMap.Testing"); 

});
```

in Scrutor:

```cs
collection.Scan(scan => scan
     // We start out with all types in the assembly of ITransientService
    .FromAssemblyOf<ITransientService>()
        // AddClasses starts out with all public, non-abstract types in this
        // assembly. These types are then filtered by the delegate passed to the
        // method. In this case, we filter out only the classes that are assignable
        // to ITransientService.
        .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<ITransientService>())
            // We then specify what type we want to register these classes as.
            // In this case, we want to register the types as all of its implemented
            // interfaces. So if a type implements 3 interfaces; A, B, C, we'd end
            // up with three separate registrations.
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            // And lastly, we specify the lifetime of these registrations.
            .WithTransientLifetime()
        // Here we start again, with a new full set of classes from the assembly
        // above. This time, filtering out only the classes assignable to
        // IScopedService.
        .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<IScopedService>())
            // Now, we just want to register these types as a single interface,
            // IScopedService.
            .As<IScopedService>()
            // And again, just specify the lifetime.
            .WithScopedLifetime());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will register all classes which implemented some interfaces as StructureMap does by default:

```
services.Scan(scan => scan
    .FromAssemblyOf<IService>()
    .AddClasses()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .WithTransientLifetime());
```

Answer (score 0):

for all type of service life time you can define

```
services.Scan(scan => scan
      .FromAssemblyOf<IApplicationService>()

      .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<IScopedDependency>())
      .AsMatchingInterface()
      .WithScopedLifetime()

      .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<ISingletonDependency>())
      .AsMatchingInterface()
      .WithSingletonLifetime()

      .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<ITransientDependency>())
      .AsMatchingInterface()
      .WithTransientLifetime()
);
```

where interfaces are

```
public interface IApplicationService { }
public interface IScopedDependency { }
public interface ITransientDependency { }
public interface ISingletonDependency { }
```

and for sample in a interface

```
public interface IUserService : IScopedDependency { }
public class UserService: IUserService { }
```