# Register services with child interface type using Scrutor

Tags: c#, asp.net, scrutor

I have the following interfaces:

```cs
public interface IValidator
{
    Task<Response> Validate(object request);
}
```

```cs
public interface IFirstChildValidator : IValidator
```

```cs
public interface ISecondChildValidator : IValidator
```

I have some services that implement the first and the second validators.

Before using [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor), I registered the services manually, and everything worked as expected:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IFirstChildValidator, FirstBar>();
services.AddScoped<IFirstChildValidator, FirstFoo>();

services.AddScoped<ISecondChildValidator, SecondBar>();
services.AddScoped<ISecondChildValidator, SecondFoo>();
```

and I could inject a specific validator to my other services:

```cs
private readonly IEnumerable<IFristValidator> _firstValidators;
// ctor injection
```

However, when I try to auto-register (the first validator as an example) using Scrutor:

```cs
services.Scan(scan => scan
    .FromAssemblyOf<IFirstChildValidator >()
    .AddClasses(classes => classes
        .InNamespaces("my.namespace")
        .AssignableTo<IFirstChildValidator>())
    .UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Replace(ReplacementBehavior.ImplementationType))
.AsImplementedInterfaces()
.WithScopedLifetim();
```

The injected type is the parent validator (i.e. `IValidator`), and the injected array of the specific implementation is left empty.

How can I achieve auto-register as specific interfaces as types?

Comment: Not an expert, but looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52320413/how-to-register-all-interface-on-assembly-in-scrutor-similar-structuremap you could try to swap 'AsImplementedInterfaces' to 'AsMatchingInterface'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove the `UsingRegistrationStrategy` this defines how to handle duplicates, in your case you want ALL of its implementations.

You can also replace it with `.UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Append)`

```
services.Scan(scan => scan
    .FromAssemblyOf<IFirstChildValidator>()
    .AddClasses(classes => classes
        .InNamespaces("my.namespace")
        .AssignableTo<IFirstChildValidator>())
.AsImplementedInterfaces()
.WithScopedLifetime());
```

Here a [.NET FIddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ASspUq)

Comment: This will make the service type as the parent interface, i.e. `IValidator`. I want the type to be `IFirstChildValidator`.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I add a .NET Fiddle where I show the implemented interfaces and the concrete object name, feel free to adjust on your particular use case to reproduce your behavior.