# Resolve and Register services using Scrutor in Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, scrutor

i have an interface(IDomainService) and a (lot) like it in my app which i mark more interfaces with it(IProductionLineTitleDuplicationChecker ) like what u will see in the rest:

```
public interface IDomainService
    {

    }
```

```
public interface IProductionLineTitleDuplicationChecker : IDomainService
    {
        ///
    }
```

and the implementation like this:

```
public class ProductionLineTitleDuplicationChecker : IProductionLineTitleDuplicationChecker
    {
        private readonly IProductionLineRepository _productionLineRepository;

        public ProductionLineTitleDuplicationChecker(IProductionLineRepository productionLineRepository)
        {
            _productionLineRepository = productionLineRepository;
        }

        public bool IsDuplicated(string productionLineTitle)
        {
            ///
        }
    }
```

right now im using the **built-in DI-container** to **resolve and register** the services but i want to change it and use **scrutor** instead

how can i resolve and register my **Services** using **scrutor**?

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the solution:**

```
 protected IServiceCollection _serviceCollection;
 public virtual void Register(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, )
        {
            _serviceCollection = serviceCollection;
             RegisterTransient<IDomainService>();
        }

        private void RegisterTransient<TRegisterBase>()
        {
            _serviceCollection.Scan(s =>
                s.FromApplicationDependencies()
                    .AddClasses(c => c.AssignableTo<TRegisterBase>())
                    .UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Throw)
                    .AsMatchingInterface()
                    .WithTransientLifetime());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just leverage the `Scrutor` extension methods for `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection`. In your `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    serviceCollection
        .Scan(x => x.FromAssemblyOf<ProductionLineTitleDuplicationChecker>()
            .AddClasses()
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .WithTransientLifetime());
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work sir

Comment: @HassanJalali this will work. We use scrutor in some of our applications. But you must determine which assembly to load classes from, and what classes to filter to your liking, etc. Without seeing your application, I can only point you in the right direction.

Comment: as I mentioned before I have a marker interface and I'm looking for a solution to only give that interface and find all the concrete

Answer (score 0):

I think your situation is consistent with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69809505/18789859), please try to use the way inside:

```
services.Scan(scan => scan
    .FromAssemblyOf<IProductionLineTitleDuplicationChecker>()
    .AddClasses(classes => classes
        .AssignableTo<IProductionLineTitleDuplicationChecker>())
.AsImplementedInterfaces()
.WithScopedLifetime());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    services.Scan(scan => scan
        .FromAssemblyOf<IProductionLineTitleDuplicationChecker>()
        .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<IDomainService>())
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .WithScopedLifetime());
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response and the article 
I found the solution for this situations